# Can't use PhantomJS render options in Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phantomjs, poltergeist

Apologies in advance for the newbish question, but I've spent hours on SO and elsewhere trying to figure this out, to no avail.

I'm using [Poltergeist](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist) as my Capybara driver in a Ruby on Rails app, to create and save screenshots with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), and I noticed a strange discrepancy.

Here is an example of [the syntax](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html) for creating a screenshot using PhantomJS directly:

```
page.render('google_home.jpeg', {format: 'jpeg', quality: '100'});
```

I wanted to use Poltergeist to achieve the same thing -- specifically, to take a screenshot at a low resolution (to produce a thumbnail). So I tried Poltergeist's [documented method](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#taking-screenshots-with-some-extensions):

> By default, only the viewport will be rendered (the part of the page that is in view). To render the entire page, use `save_screenshot('/path/to/file.png', :full => true)`.

Notice that the arguments are different. In Poltergeist, the method accepts a filename and a hash containing the key `full`, whereas in PhantomJS the method accepts a filename and a hash containing the keys `format` and `quality`. And yet, as I understand it, Poltergeist is simply passing its arguments into PhantomJS' `render` method anyway, so I don't understand what's going on.

Specifically, I looked into Poltergeist's source code, and traced the `save_screenshot` method (which is simply an alias of `render`) to [here](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/master/lib/capybara/poltergeist/browser.rb):

```
def render(path, options = {})
  check_render_options!(options)
  command 'render', path.to_s, !!options[:full], options[:selector]
end
```

And this is where I lose the plot. I can successfully use the Poltergeist syntax to accomplish exactly what it says will happen (setting `full` to true takes a screenshot of the whole page; `false` just captures the viewport), but I can't figure out why this works when PhantomJS itself doesn't even accept `full` as an argument.

Worse, I actually need to adjust the quality, but there doesn't seem to be any way to do this in Poltergeist. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: It's pretty obvious from the way that `save_screenshot` is written that you can't pass options such as the quality, but the format is usually determined from the target filename in PhantomJS. Also, if you're trying to produce a thumbnail, then PhantomJS alone can't do that. You can only crop to a part of the page (through a  selector), but you can't scale the image. Can you clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks! According to [this](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html), you can crop without selectors using `clipRect` in PhantomJS. I'm trying to capture the top portion of a page (roughly a typical laptop screen's real estate -- so 1024x768 or so) but at low-res, which is what the PhantomJS `quality` option is supposed to accomplish. But I can't figure out a) why Poltergeist doesn't allow that option and b) how the `full` option works when even PhantomJS' `render` method doesn't have that toggling functionality. Does that make sense?

Comment: a) I haven't tried it, but I suspect `full` would render the full page which might be larger than the viewport. Think of it as though the browser window has such a height that no scrollbar is visible. b) You shouldn't confuse `quality` with resolution. `quality` means the strength of lossy jpeg compression and not the number of pixels.

Comment: A) Sorry, I should have been clearer. `Full` _does_ indeed render the full page, rather than the viewport. But since Poltergeist's `save_screenshot` is basically a wrapper for Phantom's `render` (right?), I don't understand how this functionality works when the underlying Phantom `render` method itself doesn't even have an argument available for viewport-only rendering. B) Point taken. However, I'd still like to access the `quality` functionality from Poltergeist if it's possible.

Comment: Succinctly, the Poltergeist readme describes its `save_screenshot` method as follows: "this works the same way as the PhantomJS render feature." But it doesn't seem to, and I'm principally wondering if it's because I'm not using it correctly or because it's actually not the same as Phantom's `render`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the quality option to through Poltergeist to the underlying PhantomJS script, because no options are passed in as [seen in the code](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/v1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/compiled/browser.js#L488) (CoffeeScript is transpiled into JavaScript, so the actual code is [here](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/v1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/browser.coffee#L361)). However, the project is open source, so you can easily add this functionality to the `save_screenshot` function and the underlying PhantomJS script (don't forget to create a pull request).

---

When `:full` is false or unset, then only the viewport is rendered, because the [`page.clipRect`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/clip-rect.html) property is used to crop the rendering to the current viewport size.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't found that section of the Poltergeist code -- helps clear things up. Appreciated!

Comment: Note, that any change you do, should actually be done in the [CoffeeScript file](https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/blob/v1.8.1/lib/capybara/poltergeist/client/browser.coffee#L361) so that it can be later compiled into JavaScript.